# Is there a name for the traditional dress of Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

In different religions and cultures, it's common to have names for certain types of notable dress. Examples being the karategi, the kimono, the kasaya.

Is there a name for the dress of Jedi and Jedi initiates?

Commonly, we see them in just robes, but in Episodes II and III we see Obi-Wan and Anakin in "combat" dress, and I'd be interested in names for all of that gear, too. The Padawan's in the prequels also seem to have their own outfit.

Here are some of the varieties seen:

[image] [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_apparel mentions something called an obi, but doesn't say exactly what it is.

Comment: The Jedi Manual simply refers to it as "attire"

Comment: @randal'thor An obi is that sash you see below their belts (it's Japanese for sash).

Comment: That's what I hate about the prequals... Obiwan was meant to be in hiding (look over like, not getkilled by jedi hunter). So he is shown in a cloak. YET the prequals then made this the jedi attire. Let's hide being a jedi by dressing as a jedi

Answer (score 3):

The [Jedi Path Manual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)) simply refers to it as "**attire**":

> The dress of a Jedi Initiate is essentially that of a Jedi Padawan,
> Knight or Master. Tan or gray tunic. boots, belt — everything but the
> robe. The attire is not exactly the same as that worn by your elders,
> but it will identify you as a Jedi. When you finally step outside
> these to walk the galaxy, the same clothes you consider ordinary will
> be a symbol. People will approach you looking for wisdom. Others will
> beg you to fight their enemies. And others will attack you.

[image]

---

It's worth noting that Kenobi wasn't (at least originally) wearing a *traditional Jedi outfit*, he was simply wearing the desert robes of a hermit. It wasn't until the introduction of the Emperor and then other Jedi characters in the prequels that hooded robes became the main fashion choice for the Jedi.

> As the first Jedi established in the Star Wars saga, Kenobi's outfit
> became the basis for the many Jedi characters who would follow. [Costume Designer John Mollo]
> designed the costume to be the robes of a hermit rather than a Jedi
> warrior, but the look stuck. *"His outfit seems to have turned into
> this sort of costume of the Jedi Knights, really,"* says  Mollo.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Costumes: The Original Trilogy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Costumes:_The_Original_Trilogy)</sup></sub>

Comment: "Attire" simply means "Clothes". So, just to clarify, you are saying that they don't have a special name for it.

Comment: So, really, Jedi Tunics and Jedi Robes?

Comment: @CreationEdge - It's alternately referred to as "attire", "uniform" and just plain "outfit". No special word is used, at least in any of the books, as far as I can recall.

Comment: Hmm. I'm really surprised! I would have thought the EU would have called them *something*. Seems like a missed opportunity for world building.

Comment: @CreationEdge Don't forget https://xkcd.com/483/

Comment: @randal'thor Bahaha, the alt text mentions *Anathem*, which I love.

Comment: @CreationEdge  I'd better reserve judgement on Neal Stephenson since I've never read his stuff ([although...](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94434/cant-remember-the-book-special-mathematical-conclave/94442#94442)), but I can say I don't like some of the people he hangs out with.